# Android Studio build errors while importing Buildbox Project

Tags: android-studio, buildbox

Here is my build.gradle(Project:Android) file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
      }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
     }
    }

    allprojects {
      repositories {
        google()
         jcenter()
       }
    }
```

And here's gradle.build(Module:app) file
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
       android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
     buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ibdadatmallik.escape"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26

    ndk {
        moduleName "player_shared"
     }
   }

     buildTypes {
       release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
    'proguard-rules.txt'
      }
      }
    }

      dependencies {
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
       compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
       compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
       compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
       compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
    }
```

Building the APK generates the following errors

Duplicate class android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$SlideDrawable found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActivityOptionsCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.BackStackState found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.BackStackState$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.Fragment found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.Fragment$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.Fragment$SavedState found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.Fragment$SavedState$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$NonConfigurationInstances found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentContainer found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager$BackStackEntry found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager$OnBackStackChangedListener found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$3 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$4 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentState found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentState$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost$DummyTabFactory found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost$SavedState found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost$SavedState$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost$TabInfo found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ListFragment found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.NavUtils found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$BigPictureStyle found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$BigTextStyle found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$InboxStyle found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImpl found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Style found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ServiceCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat$IntentBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat$IntentReader found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder$SupportParentable found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.FileProvider found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$PathStrategy found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.IntentCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.Loader found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.Loader$ForceLoadContentObserver found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.Loader$OnLoadCompleteListener found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$BroadcastRecord found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$ReceiverRecord found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$4 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$AsyncTaskResult found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$Status found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$WorkerRunnable found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.content.pm.ActivityInfoCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.database.DatabaseUtilsCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.hardware.display.DisplayManagerCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.internal.view.SupportMenu found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.internal.view.SupportMenuItem found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.internal.view.SupportSubMenu found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat$ConnectivityManagerCompatImpl found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)

Comment: hi, Your problem was solved?

Answer (score 0):

> hello follow these steps and the error will be fixed.
>    1. click on Android SDK and select "SDK platforms" and install from Android 4.0 to android 9.+ check all
>
> 2. now at the same windows click SDK Tools and select these option:
>       2.1 android SDK Build-tools 29
>       2.2 android emulator
>       2.3 android SDK platform-tools
>       2.4 android SDK tools
>       2.5 support Repository
>
>    3. after installing these all download gradle (at this time of reply gradle version is 5.4.1) download it and extract it from zip folder.
>    4. no go to file settings it will open dialog-box from there select "Build, Execution, Deployment" in side that select "Gradle" and from
>         there select "Use local gradle distribution" and give path where you
>         extract your gradle version in (step 3) and click on.
>    5. click file and select "sync project with gralde files" wait until its download and sync
>    6. now build your project and you are done if you need more help you can ask :)